# Collatz from automate the boring stuff

Tags: python, collatz

I know there are multiple posts on this question. But I could not post my code in any other way except by asking a question. Can someone please help me understand how I can stop n from being input into the collatz function each time the global scope executes.

> Write a function named collatz() that has one parameter named number. 
>    If number is even, then collatz() should print number // 2 and return this value. 
>    If number is odd, then collatz() should print and return 3 * number + 1.
>
> Then write a program that lets the user type in an integer and that keeps calling collatz() on that number 
>    until the function returns the value 1. 
>    (Amazingly enough, this sequence actually works for any integer—sooner or later, using this sequence, 
>    you’ll arrive at 1! Even mathematicians aren’t sure why. 
>    Your program is exploring what’s called the Collatz sequence, sometimes called “the simplest impossible math problem.”)# 
>    Remember to convert the return value from input() to an integer with the int() function; otherwise, it will be a string value.
>    desired output
>
> 3
>    10
>    5
>    16
>    8
>    4
>    2
>    1
>
> Input Validation
>    Add try and except statements to the previous project to detect whether the user types in a noninteger string. 
>    Normally, the int() function will raise a ValueError error if it is passed a noninteger string, as in int('puppy'). 
>    In the except clause, print a message to the user saying they must enter an integer.

```
def collatz(number):

    if number%2==0:
        number=number//2
        print(number)
    elif number%2==1:
        number=3*number+1
        print(number)

print('Enter number: ')
n=int(input())
while n!=1:
    collatz(n)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Your question is not clear. The code you've posted is specifically taking an input and putting it into your `collatz()` function. Please describe what you would like to happen instead?

Comment: The input needs to be inside the while function.

Answer (score 1):

You‘ve created an infinite loop, since your „n“ doesn‘t change within the loop and „n!=1“ is never met as long as the user doesn’t input “1” in the beginning.

Try this:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = number // 2
    else:
        number = 3 * number + 1

    print(number)
    return number

n = int(input("Enter number: "))
while n != 1:
    n = collatz(n)
```